# How to set index as variables?

Tags: python, sympy

I am building a function, which contains many loops and conditions in it.
The input of the function is an element of a list.

I want the function to generate the result so that the nex time I don't need to run through those loop. The real code is really large so I pasted the main lines as follows, which is a toy model of the real code:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

def ff(x):
    b=0
    for i in range(10000):
        for k in range(10000):
            if k/2 >20:
                for j in range(1000):
                    if j**2-j>1:
                        b += a[x]^2+a[x]
    return b

ff(2)
```

So, in fact the result of ff should be simple, but due to the loops and conditions it runs really slow. I don't want to run through the loops each time I call ff.

A bit more like the idea that the function is a tensor in tensorflow, and index is the feed value. The structure is built first and then can be executed with different feed in values. Maybe what I want is symbolic computation.

Is there a way so that I can store the result as a sturcture and next time I just feed in the value of the index.

I cannot simply feed the values of a, since a can be some other shapes.

Comment: try the `functools.lru_cache` decorator if you are using python 3.

Comment: So... Do you want to get the index of an element `x` in list `a`?

Comment: Your loops can be improved for efficiency. Instead of running multiple if statements, modify your calling of the range function so that you will only iterate through numbers that satisfy the condition like so:
`for k in range(42, 10000):`
and
`for j in range(2, 1000):`

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI: Note: Depending on Python version (whether `/` is producing `float` a la Py3, or `int` a la Py2), the first of your ranges may need to start at `41`, not `42`, to match the behavior of the `if` test.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Just to make sure, you do intend to use `XOR` in the most nested line of your loop, right?

Comment: @alfasin I mean, considering OP used `**` elsewhere in the program, I believe OP knows the difference. Mostly just making sure it wasn't a typo.

Comment: Consider creating a symbolic expression with argument like `ax` (representing the number it will be fed, rather than the index) and compiling that with [`autowrap`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/autowrap.html#sympy.utilities.autowrap.autowrap), which creates a Fortran or C function for evaluating said expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to (if you'll start analyzing what each one of the loops is actually doing...):

```
def ff(x):
    return 995900780000 * (a[x]^2+a[x])
```

This code should run *very* fast...

Comment: Or just use the `functools.lru_cache` decorator on Python 3.2+, and avoid intermingling caching logic with code logic.

Comment: Since you are basically generating a bunch of number pairs, a list of tuples would be better suited to the task.

Comment: @ArunavMAHESHWARI a list of numbers takes longer to search. We want our cache to provide O(1) for  put/get actions.

Comment: @alfasin  Thanks. But it seems that I still need to go through the loops each time I call a new index. Can't I just keep the structure of the result so next time even if I am using a new index I just feed it into the "structured result" withou going through the loops. Because it is going to be really slow if the loops are over 1000000 times.

Comment: @ShadowRanger  It won't solve the issue that I am facing. The result of ff should be a relatively simple function with the input of the index. I would like the result to be such that I generate the function first and feed it with the value of index without running through the loops each time when feeding a new index.

Comment: @ZHANGJuenjie yes , it can be simplified.... my bad for not seeing it before... updating answer

Comment: @alfasin. Thanks again for your suggestion. The real case is reall complex and the current question is juat a toy model. The real complicated code is too long to paste here and this is wht I don't want the loops and conditions again and again when calling.

Comment: Even if it's more complex it doesn't mean it can be analyzed and that the number of steps can't be reduced. It's an iterative process, start from the inner loop and analyze your way outside.

Answer (score 0):

The condition `k/2 >20` can be restated as `k > 40`; so rather than starting the k-loop from 0, start it from 41 and eliminate that condition. Likewise, the condition `j**2 - j > 1` implies that you are only interested in `j >= 2` since one solution of that is less than 0 (and you aren't interested in those values and the other is about 1.6 and the first integer greater than that is 2). So start the j loop from 2 and eliminate that condition. Finally, your b value does not depend on i, k or j, so make the rhs 1. You now have

```
def ff(x):
  b=0
  for i in range(10000):
    for k in range(41, 10000):
        for j in range(2, 1000):
                b += 1
  return b
```

The j loop will run 1000 - 2 = 998 times; k will run 10000 - 41 = 9959 times and i will run 10000 times. The total number of times that b will be incremented is `998*9959*10000` = 99390820000. That's how many times you will have added your rhs (`a[x]**2 + a[x]`) together...which, except for a different value, is what @alfasin is pointing out: your loops are effectively adding the rhs 99390820000 times so the result will be `99390820000*(a[x]**2 + a[x])` and now you never have to run the loop. Your whole function reduces to:

```
def ff(x):
    return 99390820000*(a[x]**2 + a[x])
```

The "structure" of adding something within nested loops is to multiply that something by the product of the number of times each loop is run. So if you had

```
b = 0
for i in range(6):
  for j in range(7):
    b += 1
```

the value of `b` would be `6*7`...and the answer (as always ;-)) is 42. If you were adding `f(x)` to `b` each time then the answer would be `42*f(x)`.